# Diferencia entre {} y () al usar .map

Tags: json, reactjs, firebase, map

tengo la siguiente inquietud. Me encuentro siguiendo un tutorial para recorrer una base de Firestore en una app de React. Mi duda surge ya que llego a un punto del código en el que me imprime los datos alojados en mi base haciendo uso de () a la hora de utilizar la función map, pero si uso {} no me muestra ningún resultado. A que se debe esta situación y es conveniente utilizar () o debería arreglar el código de alguna otra forma? Gracias

```
    function App() {
      const[usuarioagenda, setUsuariosAgenda] = useState([])
useEffect( ()=>{
    const getUsuarios = async()=>{
      const { docs } = await getDocs(collection(db, 'agenda'))
      const nuevoArray = docs.map(item => ({id:item.id, ...item.data()}))
      setUsuariosAgenda(nuevoArray)
    }
    getUsuarios()
  },[])
<div className="col">
        <h2>Lista de agenda</h2>
          <ul>
          {
          usuarioagenda.length !== 0 ?
          (
            usuarioagenda.map( item=>(
              <li key={item.id}>{item.nombre} -- {item.telefono} </li>
            ))
          )
          :
          (
            <span>
              Ups! No hay usuarios en tu agenda
            </span>
          )
        }
          </ul>
      </div>
);
}
```

Comment: Te recomiendo leer sobre las [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), ahí especifica cómo se usan los () y los {}. En resumen, si pones `() => funcion` funciona, pero si pones `() => {}` no funciona. Por qué? Porque en vez de un handler has pasado un *bloque de código* y debes usar `return` tal que asi: `() => { return blablabla;}`. Si pasas un handler, lo ejecuta para obtener un resultado, si pasas un bloque, debes indicar lo que devuelve. Imagino que te referías a eso, porque tu pregunta no lo aclara muy bien, la verdad.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, ya me quedó mas claro